# How can I access my photos from flickr account inside iPhone App

Tags: iphone, flickr

I'm interested in accessing photos from my **flickr** account by entering my *username* and *password*. I know how to access random images from flickr, but to get my accounts images is the trick.

I had a look at this link but link [flickr](http://code.flickr.com/blog/2009/11/19/building-authorized-flickr-apps-for-the-iphone/) but this uses web based authrorization, which I'm not a big fan of. Any ideas/insights would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am also much more exciting about flickr. Can you tell me how to get the random images or images from http://www.flickr.com/photos/********** Link, that returns JSON response. Actually I want to access images from particular user's link and want to display in Table. Please give me some idea about this. Thanks.

Comment: @Dishant I did not get any solution to this so far. So cant help you much on this. Let me know how you get along on this?

Answer (score 0):

Web based authorisation is the way the actual flickr app works -so I would say that's your only option

Comment: hmm....thats pretty surprising that the user has to enter the web-based authorization. I remember seeing some application that does it directly from the app (dont remember the app now). Is  there any other info pointer that might be of any help?